# adding elements in a list in a list in a list python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list[i] that contains 20 other lists[j] in inside that list I have other list[k] that contains 96 elements.
I am trying to that list to another list that has 96 elements.
I get the result right but the format of a list in a list in list is not there any more, I just have one list containing the whole result. To get the right result but just in one list then the code is following:

```
reslist = []
for i in range(len(listi)):
    for j in range(len(listi[i])):
        for k in range(96):
            reslist.append(listi2[k]+listi[i][j][k])
```

Like I said this give me a right result but just in a list.
I've tried to to something like this to make the more list:

```
reslist = []
for i in range(len(listi)):
    reslist.append([])
    for j in range(len(listi[i])):
        for k in range(96):
            reslist[i].append(listi2[k]+listi[i][j][k])
```

Then I the  reslist[i] with 20 as the old one abut i get reslist[j] much bigger than it supposed to be.
The format I am looking for is the same format as for the list, with 3 list inside and 96 element in each one.

I have additional question because making a new list is not required, the more ideal was maybe to add just list2[k] to the list[k] elements. I added the picture of the list that I am trying to add elements too.

In summary:
I have 2 list. option 1: instead of making new list add elements of list 2 to list 1. ( my solution in the code was to make a new list)
List one has 20 list and x list inside that 20 list and then 96 elements. list 2 only has 96 elements.
so:
list[k] = 2.5  and list[i][j][k] has 1 then the new value in list should be list[i][j][k] =3.5 and to that to all elements in the list.  I hope this is understandable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your post, the existing list structures are:

```
list1 
     - 0
         - 0 - [.....96......]
         - 1 - [.....96......]
         - 2 - [.....96......]
           |
     - 1
         - 0 - [.....96......]
         - 1 - [.....96......]
         - 2 - [.....96......]
           |
     - 2
     - 3
     - 4
       |
     - 19

list2 - [.....96......]
```

The goal is to:

- Copy `list1` to a new list
- In the new list, for each element in the lowest level sublist, add the matching element from `list2`

This code should work for that.

```
# create new list for totals
lstNew = copy.deepcopy(list1)

# process adds
for e1 in lstNew:  # 20 elements
  for e2 in e1:     # each sublist
     for i in range(len(e2)):  # 96 elements
         e2[i] += lists[i]  # add element from list2
         
print(lstNew)
```

Comment: Nice! thanks for this Mike67. I have not great understanding of list and loops but I understand the logic behind this solution and it helps alot.